# How to calculate difference in values grouped by 2 separate variables in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, analytics

Let's say we have a team variable, but we also have a time period 1 and a time period 2 variable, and a numeric grade 1-10. I want to mutate and add a variable that calculates the difference from time period 1 to time period 2.

How do I do this?

Visually the table looks like this:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMQeM.png)

Comment: `dput(df)` of the data please, not images. And expected output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat function in the data.table package called dcast( ) that allows you to transform your data from long to wide. In this case, you can use the Period variable to create 2 new columns, Period 1 and Period 2, where the values are the Grades.

```
library(data.table)

> data <- data.table(
+   Team = c("Team 1","Team 1","Team 2","Team 2","Team 3","Team 3"),
+   Period = c("Period 1","Period 2","Period 1","Period 2","Period 1","Period 2"),
+   Grade = c(75,87,42,35,10,95))
 
> data
     Team   Period Grade
1: Team 1 Period 1    75
2: Team 1 Period 2    87
3: Team 2 Period 1    42
4: Team 2 Period 2    35
5: Team 3 Period 1    10
6: Team 3 Period 2    95
 
> data2 <- dcast(
+   data = data,
+   Team ~ Period,
+   value.var = "Grade")
 
> data2
     Team Period 1 Period 2
1: Team 1       75       87
2: Team 2       42       35
3: Team 3       10       95

> data2 <- data2[,Difference := `Period 2` - `Period 1`]
 
> data2
     Team Period 1 Period 2 Difference
1: Team 1       75       87         12
2: Team 2       42       35         -7
3: Team 3       10       95         85
```

Comment: Thanks! And then in some cases there may be 1 period recorded for the team. Will that calculation automatically return NA?

Comment: @mike_mussini, yes. NA values will be introduced if any team only has a value for 1 period.

Answer (score 0):

In tidyverse syntax, we would use `pivot_wider` and `mutate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = `Time Period`, values_from = Grade) %>%
  mutate(difference = P2 - P1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Team      P1    P2 difference
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 Team 1    75    87         12
#> 2 Team 2    42    35         -7
#> 3 Team 3    10    95         85
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- data.frame(Team = paste("Team", rep(1:3, each = 2)),
                 `Time Period` = rep(c("P1", "P2"), 3),
                 Grade = c(75, 87, 42, 35, 10, 95),
                 check.names = FALSE)

df
#>     Team Time Period Grade
#> 1 Team 1          P1    75
#> 2 Team 1          P2    87
#> 3 Team 2          P1    42
#> 4 Team 2          P2    35
#> 5 Team 3          P1    10
#> 6 Team 3          P2    95
```